# Orthogonal projection onto a subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H = L^2(0,1)$ and $E$ is spanned by the set $\{f_1(t)=\sin(2\pi t), f_2(t) = \sin(4\pi t), g_0(t) = \cos(0), g_4(t) = \cos(8 \pi t)\}$. Then i need to find a vector which is closest to the function $f(t) = 3t \in H$. I know that this is equivalent to a condition
$$
                     (f-g)\perp E
$$
where $g \in E$. So using this equivalent condition and the fact that functions of $E$ can be presented as a linear combination of {$f_1(t)=\sin(2\pi t), f_2(t) = \sin(4\pi t), g_0(t) = \cos(0), g_4(t) = \cos(8 \pi t)\}$, but as a result i receive really complex integrals which are hard to compute. So any help/suggestions are apperciated.

Comment: You should use the Fourier series, sine and cosine series. Btw, the imaginary part is cero in your case.

Comment: "Then i need to find a vector which is closest to the $f(t) = 3t\in H$" - Well, I would choose $f$ itself. You can't get closer than that. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ such that
$$
      (f-\alpha f_1-\beta f_2-\gamma g_0-\delta g_4)\perp E
$$
Because $f_1,f_2,g_0,g_4$ are mutually orthogonal, then the above is equivalent to
$$
          \alpha=\frac{\langle f,f_1\rangle}{\langle f_1,f_1\rangle},\;\beta=\frac{\langle f,f_2\rangle}{\langle f_2,f_2\rangle},\;\gamma=\frac{\langle f,g_0\rangle}{\langle g_0,g_0\rangle},\;\delta = \frac{\langle f,g_4\rangle}{\langle g_4,g_4\rangle}
$$